# Visual Studio extension that by default sets breakpoints labels to its calling function names

Tags: visual-studio

Does anyone know of an extension that automatically sets a breakpoint's label to its calling function name ?

Comment: Why the close vote? This seems like a perfectly cromulent question (+1)

Comment: @Mawg: because people need to justify their ways, regardless of whether it is right or wrong. Happens very often at SO.

Comment: @Mawg: by the way I am upvoting your comment just for the "cromulent". Never heard such a thing before :)

Comment: You have never watched the Simpsons?? Read [this](http://simpsons.wikia.com/wiki/Made-up_words). Btw, Family Guy is much funnier